# bsod dmp file on server

Tags: windows, server-crashes

I have a BSOD. It seems to be hardware related. after looking at it a bit deeper I think it's a CPU issue. Am I a wrong?

```
Crash Code: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of 
error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000005, Generic Error
Arg2: fffffa801364d028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000
```

minidump:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.
BugCheck 124, {5, fffffa801364d028, 0, 0}
Probably caused by : GenuineIntel
Followup:     MachineOwner
---------


6: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000005, Generic Error
Arg2: fffffa801364d028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

DUMP_CLASS: 1
DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400
BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.23807.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.170512-0600
SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.
SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  
BIOS_VENDOR:  Dell Inc.
BIOS_VERSION:  6.4.0
BIOS_DATE:  07/23/2013
BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A05
DUMP_TYPE:  2
BUGCHECK_P1: 5
BUGCHECK_P2: fffffa801364d028
BUGCHECK_P3: 0
BUGCHECK_P4: 0
BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel
CPU_COUNT: 8
CPU_MHZ: 7cb
CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel
CPU_FAMILY: 6
CPU_MODEL: 1a
CPU_STEPPING: 5

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT_SERVER
PROCESS_NAME:  System
CURRENT_IRQL:  f

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  07-21-2017 15:05:57.0782
ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.15063.468 amd64fre

STACK_COMMAND:  kb
FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel
IMAGE_NAME:  GenuineIntel
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PCIEXPRESS
BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PCIEXPRESS
PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PCIEXPRESS
TARGET_TIME:  2017-07-19T14:40:39.000Z
OSBUILD:  7601
OSSERVICEPACK:  1000
SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0
OS_REVISION: 0
SUITE_MASK:  274
PRODUCT_TYPE:  3
OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64
OSNAME:  Windows 7

OS_LOCALE:  
USER_LCID:  0
OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2017-05-12 10:49:14
BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  170512-0600
BUILDLAB_STR:  win7sp1_ldr
BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7601.23807.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.170512-0600
ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  428
ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM
FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x124_genuineintel_pciexpress
```

Comment: Go get bluescreenview: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html You won't regret it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably CPU, or RAM...

you can try to get more information with the following command: !errrec fffffa801364d028

I suggest to test the RAM with memtest for example.